# The express session cross domain does not save the data, it gives me a new session ID for each request call from axios

Tags: node.js, express, axios, express-session

This is the file on my nodejs express server where the express sessions are initialized. Each request I make from axios post express-session  give me new session .
and req.session.save() not save data. I set credentials: to true and app.set('trust proxy', 1);  but nothing
I tested several solution seen on net but nothing worked I don't know what's wrong in my code

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials:true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, 
  methods: ['GET','POST','PUT', 'DELETE']
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(session({
  secret : '0839194082104894H31B18943',
  resave: true,
  rolling: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  unset: "destroy",
  name:'user_name',
  cookie:{
    sameSite: "none",
    secure:true,
    httpOnly:true,
    maxAge:24*60*60*1000
  }
}));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
  "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Set-Cookie, Cookie");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  next();  
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8081;

app.use(livereload())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false,}));

app.post("/users/connect_1",function(req,res){
  req.session.name = "alice";
  req.session.save()
  res.send('ok')
});


httpServer.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

this is my axios call from front-end

````
const user = {
        email:email,
        password:password
       }
  
        axios.post("http://localhost:8081/users/connect", {user},{withCredentials:true})
        .then((response) => {
         const {message,status} = response.data
               if(status == 200){

                    push('/account');
               }
               
           
        });```
````